# Intersect a layer with a feature dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro

I would like to perform an intersect of a layer with multiple layers from a feature dataset (it has about 30 layers or so), resulting in 30 different layers as well. I know I can do this as a batch process using the intersect tool, but it takes a lot of time, and I'm wondering how I could maybe optimize this. I asume this can be done using arcPy but i'm not familiar at all with it's use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with arcpy. Specify the input layer, the single feature that you want to intersect with. Then you can list all the feature classes in the dataset and intersect with each of them

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Data\Work.gdb\FeatureDataset"
input_layer = r"C:\Data\Work.gdb\InputFeature"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for f in fcList:
    output_layer = input_layer +'_intersect_'+ f
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([input_layer,f],output_layer)
```

Comment: Perfect, just getting familiar with arcpy so getting an actual example of how to use it to optimize something is great. thanks!